# Why won't Windows XP firewall use domain settings on boot?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-firewall

Although my XP workstations are connected to the domain, after booting `firewall.cpl` reports they're "using non-domain settings".

[Official literature](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb878049#_2g) tells me it's an issue with the DNS suffix of its connection not matching the DNS name on the last group policy update, however this doesn't seem right as applying `gpupdate /force` correctly fixes it to "using domain settings".

How can I get the firewall to correctly detect it's on a domain upon boot?

Comment: Note that this problem (and the solution) apply to Windows Server 2003 as well as to XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer after scouring the net and thought to post my question and answer here to help others. [Dave Nickason wrote](http://forum.soft32.com/windows/Windows-Firewall-domain-standard-profile-ftopict355088.html#1308961):

> On any workstation where the firewall is showing as using the
>   non-domain  settings, go into Services and **set the Network Location
>   Awareness service to  start automatically**, and then restart the
>   workstation or do gpupdate /force.  Setting NLA to automatic startup
>   should fix it permanently. The issue is  that with NLA set to manual,
>   it starts too slowly to get the firewall to use  the correct (domain)
>   settings.
>
> As far as I know, MS never documented this, but you'll notice that NLA
>   is  set to automatic by default in Vista.

Thanks Dave!